# undefined reference to `clock_gettime' for arm arm-linux-gnueabi

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I was trying to cross compile a file for ARM architecture using arm-lunux-gnueabi cross compiling tool chain. But I am getting below error : -

```
undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
```

Please guide me which header files or libraries should I include and how , to get rid over this error.

I am using following command for cross compiling : -

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE -C /path/to/source
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) says:

> Note
>
> Most systems require the program be linked with the librt library to
>   use these functions.

So link to the rt library with the `-lrt` flag.

Comment: I have already used see  - arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I../include -I../../   -pthread -lrt  futex_requeue_pi.c ../include/futextest.h

Comment: @PradeepGoswami -l arguments goes at the end, after your .c or .o files. Also, you're not supposed to try to compile .h files.

Comment: @nos I am using this command make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-  -C kernel/tools/testing/selftests/futex -lrt  but I am not able to move it at last ,how to move it to  last

Comment: @PradeepGoswami I don't know what the particular command that's executed that gives you this error, nor do I know what's your particular Makefile looks like, so that's quite hard give any advice..

Comment: @nos  no problem .I have some progress in this direction , thanks for providing some clues for problem.